Running apache2 web server from Ubuntu weird issues
I have recently bought a media server for my team for anime streaming website and I need it to store episodes on it, I have just configured apache2(mostly) and I have assigned static ip address, checked and ports 80 and 443 are open, forwarded port 80, when I enter my ip address in the browser it works perfectly but when I enter http://127.0.1.1/ it says "This site can’t be reached", I tried that because I wanted to check configuration for apache2 in terminal using $ sudo apachectl configtest , this appears:
AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.1.1. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message Syntax OK
This is my config:
<VirtualHost *:80>
# The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
# the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
# redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
# specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
# match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
# value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
# However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
ServerName www.example.com`

#ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

ServerAdmin myemail@gmail.com
ServerName mydomain.com
ServerAlias server.mydomain.com
DocumentRoot /media/balkanflix/SERIJALI/Balkanflix

<Directory /media/balkanflix/SERIJALI/Balkanflix>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

# For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
# enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
# include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
# following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
# after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
#Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf
</VirtualHost>

I am confused as to why is that happening when I am nearly 100% sure I configured everything correctly
I have tried making many other config files, tested on many ports, checked many times if my ports are open and forwarded correctly and they are, I have a static ip which is 192.168.1.100

Why are you using 127.0.1.1?  That's not a valid external IP address, and it's not localhost.  Did you mean 127.0.0.1?  Why aren't you using 192.168.1.100?

You indeed want to test if that server is available from other systems. So you need to use that static IP address you gave that serving system in your local network. Better even: stop using raw IP addresses, use local name resolution instead, so something like http://mediaserver.local for which you set up a name resolution in your local network.

@TimRoberts I have used that just for testing, it works on 192.168.1.100 perfectly but I still cannot seem to get it to work on my global ip or domain

@arkascha I did test it from other systems on the same network and it worked, but I need to make it public, I do not know how to do that because I am not really experienced in this field, if it helps my ISP is Telekom Serbia and my router is ZXHN H168N V3.1

By public you mean accessible outside your local network but from "the internet", I assume? OK, why didn't you say so in the question? This means you need to forward the requested port from your local router to the system where you operate that http server on. And you need to access it using the external IP address you get from your ISP, so a routable IP address, not something starting with "10...." or "192.168...." or "127...". Since that address most likely is not static you should definitely also use a short term DNS service like dyndns or similar to have a reliable name resolution.

OK, let's review.  If you're on the SAME COMPUTER as the server, you can use "http://127.0.0.1".  That will work.  If you're on the SAME NETWORK, you can use "http://192.168.1.100".  You said that works.  If you're OUTSIDE your network, then you need to know what your public IP address is, and your router/gateway needs to be configured to forward the traffic.

@TimRoberts , I have successfully set it up, thanks for help, I have also assigned my domain to it and it works
